# how to use the same input for two different scanners in two methods with formatted input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, inputstream

*I realized the issue was due to me creating a new scanner/reader object(the new scanner has a blank input), the issue still persists* - how do I use the same input stream for both methods (or) how do I use the same scanner reader for both methods

Original question: how to pass on the main method input stream to called method

So I'm taking in formatted input which is like this from geek for geeks (this is important to my error)

```
1
4
1 2 3 4
```

And I am using scanner class to read the numbers into variables. This is my code

```java
// code to print reverse of input string after reading the length of the string and no. of testcases
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i,t,n;
        String x,y;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            t=scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            REV rv=new REV();
            for (i=0;i<t;i++){
                rv.reverse();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            return;
        }
    }
}
class REV{
    public void reverse(){
        int i,a[],n;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            n=scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine()
            a= new int[n];
            for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
                a[i]=scan.nextInt();
            }
                System.out.println(a[i]);
        }catch(Exception E){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I get no output for this (java.util.NoSuchElementException if I don't use try and catch)

I am able to read the variables in the main method but my input stream becomes empty for the new method

I verified this by using `nextLine()` both in the `main()` method and `reverse()` method as shown

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int t,n;
        String x,y,z;
        t=scan.nextInt();
        x=scan.nextLine();
        n=scan.nextInt();          //to eat up the n input
        y=scan.nextLine();
        z=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(x+y);
        ....
    }
```

output-

```
141 2 3 4
```

and

```
    public void reverse(int n){
        ....
        String k,j;
        k = scan.nextLine();      //replacing n- to check what n=scanInt() reads
        j= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(x +y);
        ....
    }
```

Output is blank again (java.util.NoSuchElementException)

I think this means the input stream is empty for the `reverse()` method.
So how do I pass on the `main()` input to `reverse()`

Note: 1. if I don't use `try{}` and `catch{}` it gives me `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

2. I'm aware I have made the code needlessly a little complicated, this is due to me trying to solve this problem
3. I got the `try{}` and `catch{}` solution from [here](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/nosuchelementexception-for-nextint/18760), but it doesn't solve my empty input problem

4.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179813/java-exception-in-thread-main) made me understand the empty input exception

Comment: Instead of making an Object of Rev class, make a method reverse().
```private static void reverse(){...}```
Use ```System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));```
Also, can you post your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method instead of making an Object of a class and then calling the method. (Unless you want it that way).

Create a single `static Scanner` and use it everywhere.

`private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`

To print an `array` use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));`.

Reductant use of `scanner.nextLine()` after `Scanner.nextInt`.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, t, n;
        String x, y;

        t = scanner.nextInt();
        for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            reverse();
        }
    }

    private static void reverse() {
        int i;
        int[] a;
        int n;

        n = scanner.nextInt();
        a = new int[n];
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

[image: Output of the code above]

Is this your desired output?

Comment: Yes! That's is precisely what I require! I have further questions about it. 1. If I use public instead of private, can i use the scanner object in other methods? (I'm new to java)

Comment: Yes, you can use any Access Modifier according to your need.
See docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Sure, you can use the scanner for other methods as well, but if you gonna make a different class make a ```new Scanner``` there.